# Working of recursion in Exponential squaring?

Tags: c++, recursion, exponential

I was reading **Exponential squaring method** for fast multiplication from the codechef tutorial and i have **few doubts related to this method**

```
long long int fast_exp(int base, int exp)
{
if(exp==1)
return base;
else
{
    if(exp%2 == 0)
    {
        long long int base1 = pow(fast_exp(base, exp/2),2);
        if(base1 >= 1000000007)
        return base1%1000000007;
        else
        return base1;
    }
    else
    {
        long long int ans = (base*  pow(fast_exp(base,(exp-1)/2),2));
        if(ans >= 1000000007)
        return ans%1000000007;
        else
        return ans;
    }
  }
}
```

**My doubt is that** does this method perform **'%'** operation at every recursive step or at the last after calculate actual **base^exp**.What i personally think that it calculates **%** at last step and also when i ran this code against

```
base=345 and exp=246;
```

it gave me **garbage value**.

**I want to know that**  When **'%'** operation is taking place,at everystep or just at the last step.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little confusing so I don't actually know what you're trying to ask, but I do see your code has three major problems:

- `pow` is *floating point* exponentiation, which means you'll get rounding errors when the numbers are large enough. You can't use it when you're trying to do exact integer arithmetic.
- You seem to be trying to do arithmetic modulo a specific 30-bit modulus, which means multiplying three reduced quantities (e.g. squaring one number and then multiplying in another number) will give results up to 90 bits in size, and thus overflow `long long`, since it's probably only a 64-bit type.
- You are using signed types, but all of your code seems to be assuming all of your numbers are nonnegative.

Comment: Actually sir,my main point of concern is the modulo operator.I want to know that when mod operation is taking place.At every recursive step or after all the recursion is over

Comment: @chota: The remainder operation happens where you've written `%`. C++ doesn't know about modular arithmetic; it only knows about remainder operations.

Comment: It happens conditionally depending on the size of the current working number - I think he's asking at which depths of the recursion it is intended to fire. But I agree with all of your comments about his code - particularly the pow - and this method may not be intended to work with numbers as large as 345^246 since that is > 1000000007. I imagine that's intended to avoid overflow?

Comment: @Hurkyl i know i am asking kind of confusing thing.Let me explain you one more time i am asking that does the recursion give ans%(value) at last or does something like (a1%value*a2%value*a3%value....)%value

Comment: It will effectively give you the final answer %1000000007, although it will actually be applied at any intermediate step when you're in danger of overflowing a calculation at the next step - it depends what the calculation is currently. Note that [the Wikipedia entry for exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) does not have this %.

Comment: I meant to add: you'll get the same answer (mod 1000000007) no matter how many times the mod was applied to intermediate states, that's a property of multiplication where all results are taken mod something.

Comment: @Rup Ok..sir,you mean to say mod 100000007 is automatically getting applied at every intermediate state and due to the property of % the final answer doesn't get affected.But in the latter example(base=345,exp=246)the overflow is due to pow function and incapability of any data structure to hold this found intermediate result

Comment: No, there shouldn't be any overflow in pow. The point of this method is that you're only ever squaring numbers which you can do by just multiplying them together - you don't need to use pow.